# DateTime ranges with "holes"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, php-carbon

Let's assume we have a "big" date and time range, like

```
$big = [
   'start' => '2018-09-01 00:00:00',
   'stop'  => '2018-09-01 23:59:59'
]
```

I have to create an array with all ranges not included in another array, like the following:

```
$exclude = [
   [
      'start' => '2018-09-01 12:00:00',
      'stop'  => '2018-09-01 14:59:59'
   ],
   [
      'start' => '2018-09-01 18:00:00',
      'stop'  => '2018-09-01 19:59:59'
   ]
]
```

so that the resulting structure would be something like this:

```
$results = [
   [
      'start' => '2018-09-01 00:00:00',
      'stop'  => '2018-09-01 11:59:59'
   ],
   [
      'start' => '2018-09-01 15:00:00',
      'stop'  => '2018-09-01 17:59:59'
   ],
   [
      'start' => '2018-09-01 20:00:00',
      'stop'  => '2018-09-01 23:59:59'
   ]
]
```

**tl;dr**

I have a big date time range (like the ones wrote above) and I have to create a resulting one by removing one or more ranges coming from another structure. Something like extracting the work breaks from the day, thus keeping only the real working hours.

I'm using Carbon and Laravel, any native solution to this or should I parse the whole structure and make the holes on my own? I don't like to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: There's not going to be any native solution for something this unique.

Comment: Any idea on how to do this at best? I was thinking to convert everything in timestamp and then loop through them

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a lot on carbon but I know that Carbon extends the native DateTime class so the following code can be adapted to achieve your purpose:

```
$result=[['start'=>$big['start'],'stop'=>''],['start'=>'','stop'=>''],['start'=>'','stop'=>$big['stop']]];//you can build this with a loop if you want...

foreach($result as $k =>$value){
    switch($k){
        case 0:

            $result[$k]['stop']=(($date=date_create($exclude[0]['start']))&&$date->sub(new dateInterval('PT1S')))?$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'):'';
            unset($date);
        break;
        case 1:
            $result[$k]['start']=(($date=date_create($exclude[0]['stop']))&&$date->add(new dateInterval('PT1S')))?$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'):'';
            $result[$k]['stop']=(($date=date_create($exclude[1]['start']))&&$date->sub(new dateInterval('PT1S')))?$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'):'';
            unset($date);
        break;
        case 2:
            $result[$k]['start']=(($date=date_create($exclude[1]['stop']))&&$date->add(new dateInterval('PT1S')))?$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'):'';
            unset($date);
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try as soon as possible